# Format to percent with 10 or a lot of decimals in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a tricky problem and I don't understand what is happening and why.

I have a userform with a lot of percentage values.

[image]

These values come from an excel sheet, where they look exactly like this. A user can now change these values and put them back in that excel sheet. The user's activity also gets saved in a log sheet. All values get saved there as well. I put the values there like this:

```
Private Sub saveV_Click()
    Dim wsLog As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim tbNr As String
    j = 3
    i = 2
    Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
    With wsLog
        lastRow = findLastRow(wsLog)
        lastColumn = findLastColumn(wsLog)
        For Each tb In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(tb) = "TextBox" Then
                Select Case i
                    'case 2 and 3 values are fixed and not of any interest
                    Case 2
                        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = tb.Value
                    Case 3
                        .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = tb.Value
                    'the following cases refer to the textboxes you can see in the other picture (there are some more)
                    Case 4 To 46
                        .Cells(lastRow + 1, j).Value = tb.Value
                    Case 47 To 89
                        .Cells(lastRow + 2, j).Value = Format(tb.Value, "0.00%")
                    Case 90 To 132
                        .Cells(lastRow + 3, j).Value = Format(tb.Value, "0.00%")
                End Select
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
            If j > lastColumn Then j = 3
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The code runs fine in itself, but it doesn't format the values right.

If I use `Format(tb.Value, "0.00%")` my values will get rounded so `101,49316739%` turns to `101,49%`

I tried adding more zeros, but if I use `Format(tb.Value, "0.000%")` my value get's multiplied by 1000 so it turns to `101493%`. (even more for more zeros)

How can I save my values with ten (or more) decimals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Format` function converts a value into a `String`.  That means you code here...

```
.Cells(lastRow + 2, j).Value = Format(tb.Value, "0.00%")
```

...will take the `Double` value of `101,49316739` and convert it into the `String` value of "101,49%".  The data type of `.Cells(lastRow + 2, j).Value` is a `Variant`, but you're giving it a `Variant` of subtype `String`. Excel then has to determine if the value you're writing can actually be represented as a number. Remember, `Format` is for displaying a ***readable version*** of a number - not for ***storing values***.

Just let Excel do the formatting:

```
.Cells(lastRow + 2, j).Value = CDbl(tb.Value) \ 100    'Cast from string to double and scale.
.Cells(lastRow + 2, j).NumberFormat = "0.000000000000000%"    'Format the cell.
```

Comment: Hm, I absolutely see your point concerning `NumberFormat` vs `Format` and a big thank your for that. Your code is giving me a type mismatch error for `CDbl(tb.Value)` though. Any ideas about that?

Comment: That means whatever `tb.Value` is can't be converted to a number. You'll probably want to add some validation code, like `IsNumeric(tb.Value)`.

Comment: Already did that, because I thought the emtpy cells are the reason for the error. But it doesn't work for the numeric values as well. And these are values taken from another excel cell, where it is saved as a percent. But maybe this is something, we don't need to discuss here. (By numeric values I mean the ones you can see in the picture.)

Comment: @Tom - Does the decimal separator match your locale setting?

Comment: @Tom - If the code you posted is the code you're testing with, I don't see any validation code there. Try something like `.Cells(lastRow + 2, j).Value = CDbl(IIf(IsNumeric(tb.Value), tb.Value, 0))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120435/discussion-between-tom-and-comintern).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `format()` function you convert your value to a string, which is interpreted an formated afterwards by excel. Just use `.Cells().Value = tb.Value` and `.Cells().NumberFormat = "0.0000%"` to get your desired result.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Values still appear as `10149316739,000000000000000%`

Comment: Probably the way you are filling you textboxes is the reason for that... Can you show your code for that?

Comment: I took values like yours from excel sheet (german excel with "," as decimal separator) and it works.

Comment: It's already sorted out, see answer above. But thank your for your effort, though! :)